# получить данные из SSAS в excel, не прибегая к сводным таблицам

Tags: python, sql, excel, ssas

Для моей аналитики необходима информация из 2-х источников: SQL и SSAS,
все расчеты выполняются на Python.
если с SQL проблем нет,то вот с SSAS стоит вопрос:

**как получить результаты расчета куба, но не используя сводную таблице Excel?**

может, есть вариант  выгрузки результата расчетов SSAS в обычную таблицу Excel-таблицу на ежедневной основе?

Смысл в том, что бы минимизировать человеческое присутствие при этом процесса

*уже пытался найти способ забирать данные из ssas питоном, но результата нет(
сводные таблицы - долго загружают данные + вечная нехватка памяти
, power query - тоже долго думает и жалуется на отсутствие памяти*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось чертовски просто:

```
#use your own DLL path.
clr.AddReference ("r"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll"")
clr.AddReference ("System.Data")
from Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient import AdomdConnection , AdomdDataAdapter
from System.Data import DataSet
#use your own server name or address. and data cube name.
conn = AdomdConnection("Data Source=tooldata.amr.xxx.com;Catalog=ShiftlyCellCube;")
conn.Open()
cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
#your MDX query, if you are not familiar, you can use the excel powerpivot to build one query for you. 
cmd.CommandText = "your mdx query" 
adp = AdomdDataAdapter(cmd)
datasetParam =  DataSet()
adp.Fill(datasetParam)
conn.Close();

# datasetParam hold your result as collection a\of tables
# each tables has rows
# and each row has columns
print (datasetParam.Tables[0].Rows[0][0])
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316192/use-python-to-query-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-cube-data

Answer (score 1):

ИСПОЛНЕНИЕ MDX ЗАПРОСА ИЗ EXCEL 
Прежде всего, необходимо выполнить операцию DRILLTHROUGH на каком-нибудь показателе, т.е. спуститься к детализированным данным (детализированные данные отображаются на отдельном листе), и открыть список подключений; Открыть свойства подключения, перейти на вкладку «Определение»; Выбрать тип команды по умолчанию, а в поле текста команды разместить заранее подготовленный MDX запрос; При нажатии кнопки после проверки правильности синтаксиса запроса и наличия соответствующих прав доступа запрос исполнится на сервере, а результат будет представлен в текущем листе в виде обычной плоской таблицы.
-- Источник: https://www.dvbi.ru/articles/reading/smid/640/ArticleCategory/5/work-with-OLAP-cube-in-Excel